# Cортировка слиянием

Tags: python, сортировка-слиянием, слияние

Метод: сортировка слиянием. Нужно вывести каждый шаг и пронумеровать, у меня нормально не получается.

Мой код:

```
print('Метод сортировки слияние')
# Функция должна объединить два списка.
def two_list(a,b):
    c = [] # Список, в который будем помещать сортированные элементы.
    i = j = 0 # Два указателя, которые будут указывать на первые элементы a и b.
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b): # Цикл, пока i не привысит длины списка a и пока j не привысит длины списка b.
        if a[i] < b[j]: # Если элемент a меньше элемента b, то добавляем в список c этот(элемент а) элемент.
            c.append(a[i])
            i+=1 # Двигаем указатель i(точнее прибалем 1), чтобы перейти к следующему элементу.
        else: # Если элемент a больше элемента b, то помещаем в список элемент b.
            c.append(b[j])
            j+=1 # Двигаем указатель j(точнее прибавлем 1), чтобы перейти к следующему элементу.
    if i<len(a): # Если i не достиг конца длины а, то мы в список с добавлем все, что находилось в а с индексом i и до конца списка а.
        c+=a[i:]
    if j<len(b): # Если j не достиг конца длины b, то мы в список с добавлем все, что находилось в b с индексом j и до конца списка а.
        c+=b[j:]
    return c # Возвращаем список с.
s = list(map(int, input("Введите элементы: ").split()))
# Функция должна выполнить сортровку.
def sort(s):
    if len(s) == 1: # Если длина списка = 1, то значит, список отосртирован и ссостоит из 1 элемента.
         return s # Возвращаем элемент.
    middle = len(s)//2 # Если условие не выполняется, то находим середину списка. Длина списка деленная нацело пополам.
    left = sort(s[:middle]) # Узнаем левую часть списка, то есть от начала спика до середины(middle).
    right = sort(s[middle:])# Узнаем правую часть списка, то есть от середины до конца списка.
    print(*(left+right), sep =', ')
    return two_list(left, right) # Объединяем обе эти части, после сортировки.
print("Результат: ", *sort(s), sep = ', ')
```

Вывод в `cmd`:

```
Метод сортировки слияние
Введите элементы: 7 8 9 0 5 6
8, 9
7, 8, 9
5, 6
0, 5, 6
7, 8, 9, 0, 5, 6
Результат: , 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Про таб не забыла, просто скопировала код и вставила(так вставилось), изменила, теперь все в  порядке? Да и код хороший, хочу узнать, как записать, чтобы выводилось, как примерно на 2 фотографии.

Answer (score 0):

Типичная сортировка слиянием:

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    print('Разбиение ',alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i = j = k = 0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i]<righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Объединение ",alist)

alist = list(map(int, input().split()))
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```